# How to create babelish config file

Tags: ios, localization

I'm using [babelish](https://github.com/netbe/Babelish) command tool to create a .strings file from a doc file stored on google. 
The command is simple:

 `babelish csv2strings -i "Project Language" -L  English:en German:de French:fr --fetch`
this works only if the data in doc is:

 `key | englishString | germanString | franchString |` ..etc where key is in the first column.

but if the key is not on the first column it doesn't work

i tried the config file `.babelish.config` and add the `keys_column: myColumn` but no success.

What i'm missing ?

Comment: Hey, how did you create .bebelish.config file? I need your help regarding bebelish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [netbe](https://github.com/netbe) i manage to fix it

1. Issue is that the config file name `.babelish.config` i got some error so I rename it to `.babelish`
2. Config settings 
   `filename:"Project Language"
   langs:
     English: "en"
   fetch: true        # set to true to get file(filename) from google drive
   comments_column: 3 # Position of column for comments if any
   keys_column: 1     # Position of column for keys`

    because my doc file have this structure `Category | Key | English | Notes`
3. If you have a config file remove all arguments after csv2strings and call just `babelish csv2strings`